"Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code" after enrollment to a development team
I have two apple accounts.  Stupidly my project is written in Account A and my paid developer account is Account B.  When I tried to archive and publish under Account A, it says "Team "XXX (Personal Team)" is not enrolled in the Apple Developer Program".  But when I add a team to Account B, "Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code".  I know it is not the code itself because it runs fine when I use Account A. Just couldn't publish.
Any advice?  Many many thanks
PS I am once again stuck when I feel so close to finally publish my laughably simple app.

Is the paid developer account an "individual" or "organization" Apple Developer account? When you said: "when I add a team to Account B", I wasn't sure what you meant...

Hi @benc thank you for commenting. I have solved the issue and already published my app.   By "add a team to Acc B", I mean in the signing and capability section, there is a field you can pick the team for the app. I picked Acc B's team.

If account A is not a paid account, you will not be able to publish with it. If it was paid, it may have expired, and just need to be pay the fee to reactivate.

Go to https://developer.apple.com
click "Account" and login
choose Account A from list to the right of "Account" in the top bar

It will have a message there if something needs to fixed or updated in your account.
For Account B not being able to sign your project, it is probably due to the Bundle ID already being associated with Account A. You would need a different Bundle ID for Account B to sign it.
Do you have the private key for the distribution account on the Mac being used to sign it?  To submit for distribution, the private key for the distribution certificate needs to be present on the Mac. (check the "KeyChain Access" app)

Hello, I made a new Bundle ID and added it on the developer portal. Although it is there, "Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code" still occurs when I tried to archive it. The project can be run on the simulator though.. https://imgur.com/a/0ckWPB7  Thank you so much

Does the error say anything else? Such as anything about the private key for the account? (I added more to my answer above)

Hello @Walt Sellers, I am fairly certain I have the certificate.  But I noticed that my Team IDs on the Portal (To right corner next to my name eg "Pete Park - ABC1D2E334") and my Mac Keychain Acces (eg "Pete Park - XYZ9W8V776") do not match.  Maybe that's the reason?

Only the Mac that generated the key pair for distribution would have the private key part unless specific effort is made to move it to other computers.

As for the Team ID versus Keychain, it's hard to say.  The certificate names in my keychain have letter strings that are completely different to the Team ID in the "Membership details" section of the "Account" page in developer.apple.com. I needed to double-click the certificate in Keychain Access and see if "Organizational Unit" matches the team ID.

Thank you for getting back to me.    I have solved the issue and already published my app.
